# Can function parameters ensure that a class conforms to interface?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make a function take in a "base class" and specify that it needs to conform to some interface? For instance:

```
class A{};
class ISomeInterface{..};
class B:public A, public ISomeInterface{};
class C:public A, public ISomeInterface{};
```

Other classes (not derived from `A`) can also use `ISomeInterface`, and not every class derived from `A` should need to implement `ISomeInterface`.
Now I want to have a function take in any subclass of A as long as it's also implementing `ISomeInterface`, so something like this;

```
void doSomething(A<ISomeInterface> *a){}; // or (A&&ISomeInterface *a) or (A::ISomeInterface a*) or whatever
```

I don't want to specify B or C as parameter directly, but I want them as arguments. The only thing I know is that I want the base class to be `A` and that whatever subclass of `A` is passed must implement `ISomeInterface`. In modern languages this is really easy, but I can't seem to find out how to do this in C++. Is this what templates are for?

Comment: There are no interfaces in C++, just classes and subclasses. If you need a variable that holds a pointer to a subclass of `ISomeInterface`, say `ISomeInterface* variable;`.

Comment: I always heard this in the past: The other cool languages have interfaces, and that stupid C++ doesn't. At first, it hurted me as a C++ writer by heart. Then I started to think how such an interface feature might be implemented and compiled, and realized that this has probably to be paid with a (performance) price. That might be a reason that C++ doesn't offer it. I'm also quite sure this can be modeled more or less clean with something like a virtual function and a clever concept (or even by a template trickery to make it compile-time polymorphism).

Comment: You can't without knowing the derived type

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I need a variable that holds a pointer to a subclass of `ISomeInterface` **and** `A`. Pointing to either alone is not enough, as there are several variables in both that I need to access. And making an interface out of them combined is not an option.

Comment: If you want to say that a parameter needs to inherit from both `A` and `ISomeInterface`, think again. Why do you need such a complicated condition? It can be expressed with some template magic but templates have their price. It is better to create a single class that inherits from both `A` and `ISomeInterface`, say call it `AInterface`, and require that your other classes inherit from `AInterface`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I can't, because there are other subclasses of `A`, let's say `G` that can't implement `ISomeInterface`, while there very well may be further subclasses of `G` that may implement it. The only thing I know is that the base class will always be `A`, and that this function is only applicable for direct or indirect subclasses of A which implements `ISomeInterface`.

Comment: Would making `void doSomething` a function template and a `static_assert` or `enable_if` that checks if the type of the passed parameter is an instance of `A` and `ISomeInterface` work for you?

Comment: In C++, an abstract class (with no data members and a set of virtual functions, including a virtual destructor) is typically functionally equivalent to an interface in other languages.    In terms of this question, you can use `dynamic_cast` to do a cross-cast.   For example, if `a` is of type `A *`, then `dynamic_cast<ISomeInterface *>(a)` will give a non-null pointer if the actual object pointed to by `a` inherits from `ISomeInterface`.   That is a run-time check, not a compile-time check.

Comment: Your inheritance structure is too convoluted and you should rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

With C++20 concepts, this is trivial:

```
#include <concepts>

struct iface {
    virtual void do_a() = 0;
};

struct B : public iface {
    virtual void do_a() override {}
};

template <typename T>
struct A {
    T value;
};

template <std::derived_from<iface> T>
void call_iface(A<T> &some_a) {
    some_a.value.do_a();
}

int main() {
    A<B> a {};

    call_iface(a);

    // This won't compile
    
    // A<int> v {};
    // call_iface(v); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

With concepts you can set constraints on functions and template parameters. `std::derived_from<Derived, Base>` resolves to true only if `Base` is a base class of `Derived`.

This basically formalizes what could be done using plain SFINAE in older C++ versions. For instance, a similar result in C++11 can be achieved using `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct iface {
    virtual void do_a() = 0;
};

struct B : public iface {
    virtual void do_a() override {}
};

template <typename T>
struct A {
    T value;
};

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<iface, T>::value>::type>
void call_iface(A<T> &some_a) {
    some_a.value.do_a();
}

int main() {
    A<B> a {};

    call_iface(a);

    // This won't compile
    
    // A<int> v {};
    // call_iface(v); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

SFINAE is a neat hack that abuses the fact that a failed template substitution in C++ results in it being ignored instead of causing an error. This pattern has been recognized by the standard in C++11 and formalized by `std::enable_if` in `<type_traits>`.

Edit: Note that in this example I haven't *exactly* described your use case (i.e. *any subclass of A as long as it's also implementing ISomeInterface*), but it's easily adaptable by composing requirements.

For instance, your use case can be represented like this:

```
#include <concepts>

struct A {};

struct iface {
    virtual void do_a() = 0;
};

struct B : public A, public iface {
    virtual void do_a() override {}
};

struct C : public A {};

template <typename T>
    requires std::derived_from<T, A> && std::derived_from<T, iface>
void call_iface(T &both) {}

int main() {
    B b {};

    call_iface(b);

    // This won't compile
    
    // C v {};
    // call_iface(v); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to remove the examples which don't fit OP's requirement (so keep only last sample)

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have quite the same notion of an interface as perhaps some other modern languages do. But it does support multi-paradigm programming with both compile-time and run-time polymorphism, so you can certainly obtain an approximation.

So, let's examine what you want to happen. You want to obtain a pointer, and you want to treat it as both an `A` *and* an `ISomeInterface`. This is of course only possible if those classes are both public and unambiguous bases. And that can be checked by just attempting an implicit pointer conversion. If you are willing to involve templates, then this becomes easy:

```
namespace detail {
  // Contract: a and i point to sub-objects of the same most derived object
  void doSomething(A *a, ISomeInterface *i);
}

template<typename C> // Contract: C *is* both an A and an ISomeInterface
void doSomething(C *a) {
  detail::doSomething(a, a);
};
```

And that's it basically. The template is the public interface function, and it will fail to compile (on account of the failed conversion) if your criteria aren't met. Meanwhile, you are free to implement `detail::doSomething` as you see fit. The parameters will give you access to the corresponding parts of the object you got as input.

Comment: This approach has the unpleasant drawback of often causing extremely long and complex error messages from the compiler. C++20 concepts largely resolve this by allowing you to formally specify type constraints.

Comment: @mcilloni - Really? A **one** level template wrapper is going to cause "long and complex" error messages? I don't know how much you played with concepts yourself, but your suggestion **pessimizes** the error output. My template will illicit errors about failed pointer conversion, which IMO, aren't too difficult to follow. You honestly think a bunch of errors about a failure to satisfy a concept will be *clearer*?

Comment: I was not talking about _this_ (relatively simple) example, but to one clear drawback of just letting substitution fail without any sort of constraint. As soon as the STL gets involved, error messages have the tendency of blowing up substantially, given that especially in libstdc++ all STL containers are implemented using layers of shims. I'd rather see something like "substitution failed because T doesn't satify "derived_from<T, A>", but that's my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the derived type, you can check it in compile-time.
But if you don't know the derived type, you have to manually check it using `dynamic_cast`.

```
struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };
struct ISomeInterface { virtual ~ISomeInterface() = default; };

struct B : public A, public ISomeInterface {};
struct C : public A {};
struct D : public ISomeInterface {};

template<typename Derived>
struct inherit_both
    : std::conditional_t<
        std::is_base_of<A, Derived>::value &&
        std::is_base_of<ISomeInterface, Derived>::value,
      std::true_type, std::false_type> {};

void doSomething(A* ptr) {
  {
    auto iptr = dynamic_cast<ISomeInterface *>(ptr);
    if(iptr == nullptr)
      return;
  }

  // do something
}

int main() {

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  std::cout << inherit_both<B>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << inherit_both<C>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << inherit_both<D>::value << std::endl;

  B b;
  C c;

  doSomething(&b);
  doSomething(&c);

  return 0;
}
```